# CEPH Write Acknowledgement in case a replica node is down

Tags: amazon-s3, ceph

While a ceph write operation , standard PUT operation - in case the data node that holds the partition (based on hash) is found dead, then does the coordinator node still sends SUCCESS ACK back for write operation ?

So the question is in case one of 3 replica nodes is found unhealthy, is the WRITE operation ACKED as failure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems it will fail in write acknowledgment in case a replica node is down if replication factor > 1 (example 2)

> Data management begins with clients writing data to pools. When a client writes data to a Ceph pool, the data is sent to the primary OSD. The primary OSD commits the data locally and sends an immediate acknowledgement to the client if replication factor is 1. If the replication factor is greater than 1 (as it should be in any serious deployment) the primary OSD issues write subops to each subsidiary (secondary, tertiary, etc) OSD and awaits a response. Since we always have exactly one primary OSD, the number of subsidiary OSDs is the replication size - 1. Once all responses have arrived, depending on success, it sends acknowledgement (or failure) back to the client.